# PHP: Select part of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
```

How do I select a subset of the array, to return just [2,3,4,5,6]?

I think it should be something along the lines of:

```
$array[2-6]
```

but that's not working

Comment: use google and find array_slice on php.net

Comment: Googling `php array subset` -- first result = 'array_slice — Extract a slice of the array'.

It makes me wonder why asking on SO is preferred to Googling :(

Comment: Sorry if you through this was a silly question. I am just learning PHP and didn't think of the word "subset" until I was writing this post. I did look for an answer online before posting.

Comment: +1 for the naïve (modern language thinking) `[2-6]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want to use `array_slice($array, 1, 5)`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help - your responses were overwhelming. :)

Comment: To get the value without modifications in `$array`, you must use: `array_slice($array, 1, 5, true)` (cf. last parameter `preserve_keys`).

Answer (score 5):

Use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];    
$output = array_slice($array, 1, 5);

print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 6
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_slice http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

```
array_slice($array, 1,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_filter`

```
function filter_arr($value) {
    return 1 < $value && $value < 7;
}
array_filter($array, "filter_arr");
```

Comment: His attempted solution suggests that he's subsetting by index, not values.